# Verificar texto do arquivo

Tags: java, android

Tenho um arquivo de texto com o seguinte conteúdo:

Nome:
Numero:
Senha:

O que eu quero,é ler esse arquivo e verificar se depois do : possui alguma caractere.Outra pergunta sobre o mesmo assunto: Como posso verificar se o texto de um arquivo possui a caractere :?

Comment: `texto.contains(":")`?

Comment: Expressão regular serve perfeitamente para isso

Answer (score 1):

Para verificar se o arquivo contém o caractere ':'

```
String textoDoArquivo = FileUtils.readFileToString(seuArquivo);
if(textoDoArquivo.contains(':'){
     //O caractere está presente no arquivo
}
```